# How to disable opening WPF popup

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, popup

I have a `Popup` and a `ToggleButton`. I set a binding like this:

```
<ToggleButton x:Name="myToggle" Content="{Binding MyData.Title}" />
<Popup IsOpen="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=myToggle}" >
   <TextBlock Text="{Binding MyData.Details}" />
</Popup>
```

As you see, I bound the toggle button's content to `MyData.Title` and the popup's content to `MyData.Details`.

Now I had the criteria `MyData.ShowDetails`. If it is `true` the popup can open and if it is `false` the popup should not be opened.

How can I set a binding to achieve this?

I tested these bindings on the `Popup` but no one works:

```
Visibility="{Binding MyData.ShowDetails, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"

IsEnable="{Binding MyData.ShowDetails}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a special answer in my case. Instead of disabling `Popup`, I should disable the `ToggleButton`:

```
<ToggleButton x:Name="myToggle" Content="{Binding MyData.Title}" 
              IsEnabled="{Binding MyData.ShowDetails}"/>
<Popup IsOpen="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=myToggle}" >
   <TextBlock Text="{Binding MyData.Details}" />
</Popup>
```

It works perfect!

**Note:** This is not a general answer for `Popup`. Welcome to anyone who has an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could put a panel (Grid ) on top of all the content in your window.

That needs to have a background set but it can be low opacity if you still want to see the window content.

Make that visible only when the popup is shown and collapse otherwise.

Make sure you set focus to your popup when it's shown.

.

Bear in mind.

Popups are separate windows.

They are intended to be shown briefly and have  a number of potential drawbacks if you show them for longer periods. EG other applications can appear under them and they don't move with their "parent" window/control.

You might find a modal window is easier and suits better, depending on your exact requirements.

Just instantiate a window and use

```
PopupWindow newWindow = new PopupWindow();
newWindow.ShowDialog();
```

Where PopupWindow is just any old window styled to look like you want the popup.

This will guarantee the user can't somehow interact with any other window in your app.

.

Another possibility is to show your "popup" content in a grid which appears on top of everything inside your main window.

That's how editing data works in this:

https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/WPF-Entity-Framework-MVVM-78cdc204

The plus or minus of that approach is that it's in the one window.
--- [Brian Kress](https://www.checkthem.com/name/brian-kress/) ---